# Maps infowindow is not opening on mouseover event (coffeescript)

Tags: google-maps, coffeescript

I researched and tried everything to find a solution. I have to admit that I am no expert in coffeescript. Maybe it is an obvious mistake but I have no clue and I would be very happy if someone could help.

I created markers on google maps. With click applisteners it is possible to open specific htmls which belongs to the markers. Now i also need a infowindow for each marker, which should oben on mouseover and close when leaving.
I have no idea why it is not working. I tried other solutions, which mostly worked in javascript but not for me in coffeescript. Here is the code:

```
### define
lodash : _
backbone : Backbone
marionette : Marionette
app : app
parse : Parse
###

class MapView extends Marionette.View

  DEFAULT_CENTER : [0, 0]
  DEFAULT_ZOOM : 10

  className : "map-view"

  render : ->

    mapOptions =
      zoom: @DEFAULT_ZOOM
      streetViewControl: false
      panControl: false
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(@DEFAULT_CENTER...)
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    @map = new google.maps.Map(@el, mapOptions)

    @infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

  #[........................]

  makeJobMarker : (job) ->

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map : @map
      position : {
        lat : job.get("location").latitude,
        lng : job.get("location").longitude
      }
      icon : "/images/marker/#{job.get("jobCategory")}.png"
      animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP
      zIndex : google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1
      optimized : false
    })

    marker.addListener("mouseover", =>
      infowindow.setContent("Hello")
      infowindow.open(map,marker)
    )

    marker.addListener("click", =>
      app.router.navigate("/job/#{job.id}", trigger : true)
      app.vent.trigger("view:searchItem")

    )

    marker.jobId = job.id
    return marker

    #[.......................]
```

Comment: Looks like you're mixing up js with coffee. What's the js version that's working for you look like?

Comment: Thanks for your message! I am coding in cs and find mainly find js-tutorials to my problem. When I try to adjust the solutions to cs, they are not working. So there is no js version which is working for me at the moment. Or do I get your question wrong? The tutorial at google dev is also for js only.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in your browser with breakpoints to see if the generated javascript is as expected? Or maybe you got a working setup (jsfiddle, github) to look at?

Comment: I have to say that i have no experience with testing code with breakpoints in browsers. I just read about it and will try it tonight. Unfortunatly I have no working setup. I tested the code with http://www.tutorialspoint.com/try_coffeescript_online.php and here everything looks ok. The second addlistener is working fine, but it seems like the  first (marker.addListener("mouseover")) is ignored. Maybe I define "@infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()" at the wrong place?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're calling the class variable '@infowindow' without the instance keyword `@` in `marker.addListener "mouseover"`?

Comment: I am not sure if I get it right. You mean it shoul be like:
"@marker.addListener("mouseover", =>" ?

Comment: No, I mean in the `addListener` method, you're missing the `@` keyword for the instance variable `infowindow`

Comment: Ok, I added the @ keyword:

    marker.addListener("mouseover", =>
      @infowindow.setContent("Hello")
      @infowindow.open(map,marker)
    )

and I also looked in the browser in the jsnd it results the following error:

http://up.picr.de/21591276ox.jpg

Comment: Congratulations on finding the debugger! :) As you can see, you also need to refer to `this.map` instead of `map`, so it should be `@infowindow.open(@map,marker)`.

Comment: Thanks so much! It is working now. And also good to know how the js debugger works. My next goal is tho ad different content to different marker - we will see :) Tnx again for your help

Comment: Glad it worked! I've added the solution as an answer. You can accept it below if you think that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `@` key (`this` equivalent in javascript) to access the private members `@map` and `@infowindow`:

```
marker.addListener("mouseover", =>
  @infowindow.setContent("Hello")
  @infowindow.open(@map,marker)
)
```